# How to reset DENSE_RANK

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I have the following table

> Id,Cat1,Cat2,ColA,ColB,
>
> 1,1,1,,
>
> 2,1,1,,
>
> 3,1,2,,
>
> 4,1,3,,
>
> 5,2,11,,
>
> 6,2,12,,
>
> 7,2,12,,

I need to add a unique sequential number per grouping column of Cat2 starting at 1 BUT it has to reset back to 1 when Cat1 changes

My output should be

> Row, Id,Cat1,Cat2,ColA,ColB,
>
> 1,1,1,1,,
>
> 1,2,1,1,,
>
> 2,3,1,2,,
>
> 3,4,1,3,,
>
> 1,5,2,11,,
>
> 2,6,2,12,,
>
> 2,7,2,12,,

DENSE_RANK() works to give a unique value e.g.

```
Row= DENSE_RANK() OVER ( ORDER BY Cat2)
```

but I need it to reset itself based of another column Cat1

Comment: `Row= DENSE_RANK() OVER ( ORDER BY Cat2)` should give your desired output. Doesn't it? What's the output you receive by using the `dense_rank()`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the PARTITION BY clause on Cat1:

```
Row = DENSE_RANK() OVER ( PARTITION BY Cat1 ORDER BY Cat2)
```

The PARTITION BY clause will partition your DENSE_RANK() first based on your Cat1 before ranking them densely, which is exactly what you need.